# How to make <textarea> un-transparent

Tags: html, css, textarea

```css
label {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 186px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}

textarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label>
<aside>order id</aside>
<textarea placeholder="please enter order id, one by line" onfocus="javascript:this.style.height='100px';"
    onblur="javascript:this.style.height='30px';" class="form-control"></textarea>
...
<aside>buyer name</aside>
<input type="text" placeholder="">
</label>
```

default state:

[image]

when textarea focus on, its height will scroll down, otherwise scroll on to default state.

focus state:

[image]

the question is that the textarea background is transparent!

i attempt to set the background to grey, but still tansparent and with grey background:

[image]

so, how to make the textarea not transparent?

Comment: What browser are you using? For me, it isn't trsnsparent. I am on Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @JordanQuartermain Ubuntu16.04 Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting opacity to 1?

Answer (score 0):

have solved it, add a css z-index

```html
textarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}
```